# How to find current stack size in bytes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, it appears you can set the size of the stack with the `RUBY_THREAD_VM_STACK_SIZE` environment variable.

Is there a way to programmatically determine the current size of the stack? This would be a useful input into picking the right stack size (and would be useful for debugging `SystemStackError` / `stack level too deep` errors).

Comment: If you're blowing the stack it's often a case of accidental recursion leading to it. There are extremely rare cases when this happens due to a very complex recursive algorithm, and in that case you may want to use a different approach anyway.

Comment: @tadman Good point. In my particular case it turned out that the code was running in a fiber, which was configured with a very small stack size.

Comment: Those have a necessarily fairly thin stack as it means Ruby can handle millions of fibers at once without issue. Increasing that size increases the cost of each fiber, so do be cautious here.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no portable answer to that question, but for MRI you have [RubyVM::DEFAULT_PARAMS](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/RubyVM.html#DEFAULT_PARAMS).

On my machine:

```rb
> RubyVM::DEFAULT_PARAMS
{:thread_vm_stack_size=>1048576,
 :thread_machine_stack_size=>1048576,
 :fiber_vm_stack_size=>131072,
 :fiber_machine_stack_size=>524288}
```